# Undefined Method 'visit' after migrating to capybara from webrat in rails 3.2.12

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, webrat

We are migrating rails integration test to capybara from webrat. Replace `response.should` with `response.body.should`. Also added `require 'capybara/rails'` to spec_helper.rb. However there is an error saying `undefined method 'visit'`. Every `visit` causes an error. Here is the first 2 piece of code which causes error:

```
describe "TestPaths" do
  describe "GET /customerx_test_paths" do
    before(:each) do
      ul = FactoryGirl.build(:user_level, :sys_user_group_id => ug.id)
      u = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :user_levels => [ul], :login => 'thistest', :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password')
      visit 'authentify/'
      fill_in "login", :with => u.login
      fill_in "password", :with => 'password'
      click_button  
    end

    #customer status category
    it "should display customer status category index page" do
      visit customer_status_categories_path
      response.body.should have_selector("title", :content => "Customerx")
    end

...
end
```

The before loop is just login to the system for the rspec case below. What's wrong with the capybara code? Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you paste spec_helper.rb?

Comment: require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require "factory_girl_rails"

Comment: We moved all the 'visit' .. into 'it' loop and 'visit' is still not defined.

Comment: Where the test is located? Guess somewhere in 'requests' directory?

Comment: Are you requiring spec_helper in your spec file? (Also `before` and `it` are called blocks, not loops.)

Comment: The tests is in requests directory. After moving to features subdir, the visit became defined and the error disappears (undefined method 'visit'. Got other errosr though) after moving to features. The rails g integration_test creates requests subdir instead. It seems that we have to manually create the features subdir for capybara everytime.